# Directory Listing Denied:This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed

Tags: coldfusion

I am getting an error while trying to run CFmx code on a remote host.
                        Directory Listing Denied
          This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.

I did my coding on my "LocalHost".
Then for testing ,I copied it to a remote host "ChicaDevTestApp" to a folder “D:\inetpub\wwwroot\Aug20\AppliTest.com”.
Previously, I was able to access  the old code(in "ChicaDevTestApp") as “http:// ChicaDevTestApp” from my system.
Now since I added a new folder “Aug20”  I tried ,the url “http:// ChicaDevTestApp /Aug20/”.
But was getting the above  error.

Should I work the “path” , in the CFAdmin ?
How to run the folder “Aug20” containing my code ,from my local host?

Thanks in Advance
Vas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the virtual directory is not set up in IIS to enable directory listing. This setting can be changed in the IIS manager, what version of IIS are you running? 6 or 7?

EDIT:

I completely go the wrong idea about what you're trying to describe. What you actually want to do is to set a Default Document for that directory (the aug20 directory)... Open up IIS Manager, and select your virtual directory. Open the "Documents" tab and add the name of your "default" page to the box

Comment: Hi Loren !
I am using version 6.

Comment: Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Internet Information Services

Find your virtual directory on the left, right click > Properties

Go to the "Home Directory" tab and enable the checkbox that says "Directory Listing"